# PHP script to process NSURLRequest from iphone

Tags: php, iphone

i will be sending a POST request to login.php on my server 
from an iphone app over HTTPS. The POST is created using NSMutableURLRequest. Is there an 
example of a PHP script to process this POST on my server. The POST isn't sent as a form as 
such , anyway not that i think it is. Not sure how NSMutableURLRequest formats this.
I just need to know how to access the POST data on the server with the php script.

All the examples ive seen regarding php scripts processing POSTS seem to be do with forms.
So how do i process this?
Any links etc most welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access any POST data via the [`$_POST` array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) in PHP:

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method.

---

The [HTTP POST method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_POST) itself has nothing to do with forms (it is just often used with forms). It is another way to transmit data, compared to GET.

With GET, the parameters are appended to the URL, with POST, they are in the HTTP message body.

[Make yourself familiar with HTTP.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http)

Comment: Hi , i tried sending the POST and i can see its going out to the server using Wireshark. Just testin with http initially to get it working

the post has the following data

username=user&password=secret

Then on the server, i have process.php script and for now i just want to echo the values in the POST

so i have the following
<?php
echo "Username = {$_POST['username']}";
echo "Password = {$_POST['password']}";
?>

However when i run the php script after the event
like this  php process.php from a bash shell then
i get nothing printed out. What could be going on?

Thanks